# How to use a custom path when running test in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have different toolboxes and dependencies between toolboxes is not allowed. Each new function in a toolbox also needs to have a test within the testsuite of that toolbox to ensure nothing breaks when code is changed.

When running a test within a toolbox I want the test to ensure that it only can access code from that toolbox. How to do this?

Comment: If you're using MATLAB's formal unit test framework, there are specific functions to handle temporary path management during tests e.g. [matlab.unittest.fixtures.pathfixture](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.fixtures.pathfixture-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. However, from the documentation it says it temporarily adds folders to the path variable. What I am looking for is how to create a temporarily totally new path variable

Comment: You can get the current path with `p = path` and set it with `path(newpath)`. You can go wild cleaning that up as you require in the meantime, including temporary setups if needed. Which bit of this are you stuck with?